# Checking if loaded class has annotations in Java EE web application

Tags: jakarta-ee, reflection, annotations

I wrote my class annotation:

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface CAnnotation {
   String name();
}
```

Next I wrote my lib:

```
public class Customized implements Serializable {

    @CAnnotation(name="getCustomer")
    public String getCustomer(int id){
        return "ABCABC";
    } 
}
```

Now I read in web application deployed to GlassFish 4.1.1 `customized.jar` like this:

```
public void inir(){
    System.out.println("---------------");
    System.out.println("---------------");
    for (Method metoda : getUserClass().getMethods()) {
        System.out.println("---------------"
                + "\n" + metoda.isAnnotationPresent(CAnnotation.class)
                + "\n" + metoda.getName()
        );
        for (Annotation annotation : metoda.getAnnotations()) {
            System.out.println("---------------"
                    + "\n" + annotation
            );
        }
        if (metoda.getAnnotation(CAnnotation.class) instanceof CAnnotation) {
            System.out.println("---------------");
            System.out.println(":" + metoda + " " + metoda.getAnnotation(CAnnotation.class).name());
            System.out.println("---------------");
        }
    }
}


public Class getUserClass() {
    File file = new File("./Customized.jar");
    try {
        JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(file.getPath());
        Enumeration e = jarFile.entries();
        URL[] urls = {new URL("jar:file:" + file.getPath() + "!/")};
        URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry je = (JarEntry) e.nextElement();
            if (je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")) {
                continue;
            }
            String className = je.getName().substring(0, je.getName().length() - 6);
            className = className.replace('/', '.');
            Class c = cl.loadClass(className);
            return c;
        }
        return null;
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("" + ex);
        return null;
    }

}
```

And in console I get this:

```
Info:   ---------------
Info:   ---------------
Info:   ---------------
false
getCustomer
Info:   ---------------
...
```

I checked it in desktop application and I get "true".
So what is a difference between web and desktop app, in the web appliction dont have my annotations?
What am I doing wrong?
I checked a file on server using the jd-gui (Java Decompiler) and `customized.jar` has annotations.
I didn't add anything in `web.xml` or `faces-config.xml`.

Comment: Is your customized.jar deployed with your web app?

Comment: No, first deploye app, next deploye jar.